# Can I hide only the Bootstrap Modal's content?

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to only hide the content of the modal, not the modal itself, so when I click next, it shows the content from the next modal, but it doesn't reopen the next modal, but changes only to the content.
There's a code of JQuery which creates the Modals accord to the amount of array elements in a text file and a function with which I try to change the Modal content with next/previous buttons

```
$("#Modals_"+index).each(function () {
    var currentModal = $(this);
    // Modal next
    currentModal.find('.btn-next').click(function () {
        currentModal.modal('hide');
        currentModal.closest("div[id^='Modals_']").nextAll("div[id^='Modals_']").first().modal('show');
    });
    //Modal previous
    currentModal.find('.btn-prev').click(function () {
        currentModal.modal('hide');
        currentModal.closest("div[id^='Modals_']").prevAll("div[id^='Modals_']").first().modal('show');
    });
});
```

```html
"<pre><button class=\"btn modal-button\" data-toggle=\"modal\" id=\"buttonOn_" + index + "\" data-target=\"#Modals_" + index + "\" value=\"open Modal\"></button>\n" +
"     <h3 class=\"modal-title_" + index + "\"></h3>\n" +
"</pre>\n" +
"<div class=\"modal fade\" id=\"Modals_" + index + "\" tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"dialog\" aria-labelledby=\"ModalCenterTitle\" aria-hidden=\"true\">\n" +
"   <div class=\"modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered\">\n" +
"      <div class=\"modal-content\" id=\"modal-content_" + index + "\">\n" +
"         <div class=\"modal-body picture\" id=\"modal-body_" + index + "\">\n" +
"            <img class=\"img-responsive\" id=\"modalPic_" + index + "\" src=\"\" alt=\"...\">\n" +
"            <h2 id=\"modal-title_" + index + "\" class=\"modal-title_" + index + "\"></h2>\n" +
"            <p id=\"modal-description_" + index + "\" class=\"modal-description_" + index + "\"></p>\n" +
"            <button class=\"btn-prev\" id=\"previous_"+index+"\" onclick=\"\">Previous</button>\n" +
"            <button class=\"btn-next\" id=\"next_"+index+"\" onclick=\"\">Next</button>\n" +
"            <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" style='color: white;'>Close</button>\n" +
"         </div>\n" +
"      </div>\n" +
"   </div>\n" +
"</div>\n");
```

```js
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nameLV] => Loku līnijas mezgls
            [descriptionLV] => Mezgls, kas izskatās pēc loka
            [nameEN] => Bowline knot
            [descriptionEN] => Angliski
            [nameRU] => Узел носовой линии
            [descriptionRU] => Krieviski
            [Image] => bowline.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nameLV] => Astoņnieku mezgls
            [descriptionLV] => Mezgls 8 formā
            [nameEN] => Figure Eight knot
            [descriptionEN] => Angliski
            [nameRU] => Восьмерка узел
            [descriptionRU] => Krieviski
            [Image] => figureEight.png
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nameLV] => Makšķernieku mezgls
            [descriptionLV] => Izmanto tikai un vienīgi copermaņi
            [nameEN] => Fishermans knot
            [descriptionEN] => Used only and just only by fishermen fisherweman gender neutral
            [nameRU] => Copermanskij uzel
            [descriptionRU] => Tolko copermanski nuzno etot uzel
            [Image] => FishermansStyle.png
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [nameLV] => Sakabes mezgls
            [descriptionLV] => Mezgls ko izmanto lai sakabinātu lietas
            [nameEN] => Bunt Line Hitch knot
            [descriptionEN] => Angliski
            [nameRU] => Узел сцепления
            [descriptionRU] => Krieviski
            [Image] => buntlineHitch.png
        )

)
LV
EN
```

That is the array which is returned in php when I call back the .txt file with Json encoded data.

Comment: you can do with ajax, don't use multiple modals, just one model and when you click on next or previous, make api call with all the data and set that data to modal.

Comment: Client has asked me, to display multiple Modals as info brokers, so you can click on each one and view more info about the specific one, but I need to be able to click through all of them whilst Modal is open

Comment: you want something like [this](https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/71H5HWFEWP) ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but my modal content is not hardcoded, content for my modals are from a JSON array in a text file

Comment: please update your question with JSON array so I can help

Comment: That's not valid HTML or JSON...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have tried to solve your problem with one model, which is working fine, I can understand that your client is requesting for multiple modals but it's just code duplication and rework. just check this with json if it can help you out.

```js
var json = [{
 "title": "title1",
 "image": "image1",
 "description": "description1"
}, {
 "title": "title2",
 "image": "image2",
 "description": "description2"
}];

$(function() {
  $("#next-btn").on("click", function() {
      var currentId = $(document).find("#position").val();
      id = $("#"+currentId).next();
      nextId = id.data("json")
      btnId = id.attr("id");
      if(nextId!==undefined) {
        openModal(nextId, btnId);
      } else {
        alert("last");
      }
  });
  
  $("#prev-btn").on("click", function() {
      var currentId = $(document).find("#position").val();
      id = $("#"+currentId).prev();
      prevId = id.data("json");
      btnId = id.attr("id");
      if(prevId!==undefined) {
        openModal(prevId, btnId);
      } else {
        alert("first");
      }
  });
  
  $(".openmodal").on("click", function() {  
      openModal($(this).data("json"), $(this).attr('id'));
  });
});


function openModal(id, btnId) {
    var js = json[id];
    title = js.title;
    image = js.image;
    description = js.description;
    $("#position").val(btnId);
    $(".modal-title").html(title);
    $(".modal-body").html("image"+image+", description"+description);
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
  <h3 class="modal-title">Heading</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
  
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="text" name="current" value="" id="position" />
  <button id="prev-btn" class="btn btn-warning">Prev</button>
        <button id="next-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
 </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn1" name="modal-open" data-json=0 class="openmodal btn btn-success" value="Open Model1" />

<input type="button" id="btn2" name="modal-open" data-json=1 class="openmodal btn btn-success" value="Open Model2" />
```